# SQL query to check if any cell in a column matches with a set of given strings.

Tags: mysql

I have this data in a column

```
Steffi | ND Baumecker | Cassy
```

I would like to do a query to find if any of the above exist in another column

example of other column (Artist being column name)

```
Artist
Steffi
Derrick Carter
Ben Klock
Craig Richards
```

I don't think a LIKE will work here so wondering what query I can use to return the artist name from column 'Artist' when a match is made - so in the above example 'Steffi' would be returned.

Would I also need to remove the spaces before and after the | in the first column?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you think like will work. In fact, a simple = will work, but I would use in: select artist from MYTABLE where artist in ('steffi','no baumecker','cassy')

Comment: Thanks kainaw - wondering how I can convert Steffi | ND Baumecker | Cassy to ('Steffi','ND Baumecker','Cassy') from within a query?

Comment: you can shoot a replace('|', ',') and then use mysql function FIND_IN_SET

Answer (score 4):

If I understand properly your problem: you want to filter rows using values from a column and searching for these values in another column?

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, a.nickname
FROM artist AS a
WHERE a.related_nickname IN (
    SELECT sa.nickname
    FROM artist AS sa
    WHERE sa.popularity > 30
)
```

MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

It seems that you are trying to achieve a complicated task and I'd advise you to try a couple of things.

- Subqueries are useful but makes your queries much slower so using two queries might speed things up. The first query would pick the values that will be used for filtering and the second query will search rows.
- If you filter by string, consider using indexes on your table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html